# Add help text for a field in CKeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I need to add a help text for url field in CKeditor. I am using CKeditor version 4.5.8. Is there a way to add help text for this field? Please help.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqDob.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a placeholder. I have added a sample config setting below. You can modify the below example to fit your needs.

```
<input name="url" placeholder="Type here..."></textarea>

var config = {};
config.placeholder = 'some value'; 
CKEDITOR.replace("myeditor" , config );
```

Hope that helps.